# What does (volitional form) + ったって+(potential form of same verb) mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I came across this and don't quite understand is meaning. One character orders another to forget something, who nods agreement but thinks to themselves:

> 忘れようったって忘れられない

What does 忘れようったって mean here? Something like "even if I want to forget"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this [デジタル大辞泉's entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-561378):

> たって［連語］
>   ［連語］《格助詞「と」と動詞「いう」の連用形に接続助詞「たって」の付いた「といったって」の音変化》名詞、活用語の終止形、動詞と一部の助動詞の命令形、一部の助詞に付く。上に促音の付いた「ったって」の形をとることが多い。ある事柄を認めるにしても、全面的にではないという気持ちを表す。**…といっても。…としても。**「登山―、ハイキング程度さ」「来いっ―すぐには行けない」「買うっ―近くに店はないよ」
>   [補説]打ち解けた話し言葉で用いられる。

So `ったって` after a noun, a dictionary/imperative form of a verb, or a dictionary form of an adjective is a contracted form of `と言ったって` (lit. "although one says ～", "even if they say ～").

忘れようったって忘れられない literally means "Even if I say I will forget, I can't forget".

Note that `たって` directly after te-form is not a contracted form of と言ったって, but [this](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/137398/meaning/m0u/):

> ［接助］《過去の助動詞「た」の終止形に接続助詞「とて」の付いた「たとて」の音変化》動詞・形容詞、一部の助動詞の連用形に付く。ガ・ナ・バ・マ行の五段活用動詞に付く場合は「だって」となる。逆接の仮定条件を表す。**…ても。…たとしても。**「笑われ―かまわない」「いくら捜し―いるはずがない」

Example:

> - 走ったって問題ない。 There's no problem if I run. (te-form of 走る happens to be 走っ)
> - 走るったって、今日は雨だよ。 Even if you say you run, it's raining today.

Answer (score 8):

***Double contraction*** is taking place here.

> 「[忘]{わす}れようったって」＝
>
> 「忘れようと言ったって」

which means:

> 「『忘れよう』と言っても」≒
>
> 「『忘れよう』と言ったとしても」
>
> = "Even if I/you/we said 'Let's forget!'"

The last part of the sentence 「忘れられない」, of course, means "I/you/we can't (forget)."

***This construct, which uses the same verb twice, is very common.  In its first appearance, the verb can be in a few different forms such as volitional,  imperative, etc., but in its second appearance, the verb must be put in a negative form.***

「[食]{く}えったって食えねえよ、[納豆]{なっとう}だけは！」= "Just can't eat nattou no matter what!"

(Notice I did not employ the silly literal TL of "Even if someone told me to eat nattou, I could not eat it!")

「ハワイに[連]{つ}れてってって言われても、連れていけないよ～。お[金]{かね}ないもん！」　Yes, I did use 「連れてってって」 correctly. = 「連れていってって」 = 「連れていってと」

"You ask me to take you to Hawaii, but I can't.  I ain't got much money!"

Comment: According to the book I read, the volitional form + ったって・たって means volitional form + としても, so it is something like even if I try to forget, I am not able to. I think.