# Help understanding the meaning: 「ごまかしたってちゃんと聞いたんだからな」

Tags: grammar, sentence, ending, structure

I've been trying to get the meaning of this sentence for a while and I just can't figure out the grammatical structures behind it. The sentence is:

> ごまかしたってちゃんと聞いたんだからな

I found out that ごまかした the plain past form is from ごまかす and the って is probably for bringing up a topic (?). Also 聞いた is the plain past form from 聞く. But I don't know what to do with the ちゃんと and also the ending of the sentence. What does the んだ to the verb and what is the sentence ending からな?

Comment: 〜たって may be confusing. I hope these posts help you [30696](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30696/what-does-volitional-form-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6potential-form-of-same-verb-mean) and [2055](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/is-it-true-that-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6-is-the-colloquial-form-of-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d%e3%81%a7)

Answer (score 1):

- This たって means "even if" or "even though". See [JLPT N3 Grammar: たって (tatte) Meaning](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-tatte-meaning/)
- For the meaning of ごまかす, see [Meaning of ごまかす](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94402/5010)
- This んだ is explanatory-の used to convince/persuade someone.
- から is basically "because", but here it's more like "...so, you know what".

> ごまかしたってちゃんと聞いたんだからな
> Even if you try to hide it, I heard it, you know.